# Can we predict / formulate regression equation for a dichotomous variables and scale predictors ?

Tags: predictive-models

Can we predict / formulate regression equation for a dichotomous variables and scale predictors ?
Example : If I want to predict if applicant will success or fail in interview based on scale variables like GPA , etc ?
Can we do that statistically ?

Comment: Are you asking for logistic regression? what kinds of regressions are implied? Regression trees and neural networks as well?

Comment: Yes. I'm asking about logistic regression. Indeed I feel I'm in a loop and can't make a decision to detect the right test since there are many of regression tests.

Comment: If I read the Wikipedia correctly, then GPA is a weighed mean which implies a metric scale. If you know about logistic Regression but don't know how to predict a dichotomous result from a metric predictor, than I don't understand the problem. Why is this not a straightforward use of logistic Regression?

Comment: I just tried the logistic Regression Test ; I got the value of -2 Log likelihood
.000 and a message "Estimation terminated at iteration number 20 because maximum iterations has been reached. Final solution cannot be found." What that's mean and how I can deal with it ?

Comment: It probably means, that your data are tricky to deal with and that whatever your software is, it uses an algorithm that does not converge with these particular data. Without seeing your data it will be difficult to solve that problem.I guess that there is complete separation. All small GPA lead to zero, all large GPA lead to 1 and the computer cannot determine the slope of the logistic function as many different slopes could explain the phenomenon.

Comment: Where I can show you the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Logistic Regression will be the wrong answer in case of complete separation. Using Google I found, that the error message given in the comments is what SPSS writes in case of complete Separation. That's not to bad, as it is particularly easy to give a threshold in cases of complete Separation. Any number in between the largest GAP that leads to a Zero and the smallest that leads to a One will do. You might use the mean between those two as a threshold.

Comment: That's make a sense! Is it normal to get Nagelkerke R Square
1.000 ? I find it not acceptable ? The value of Cox & Snell R Square is
.736 . What I should adopt in reporting the Nagelkerke or the cox value in the explanation of variation ?

Comment: In case of complete separation, logistic regression is the wrong method. You should not use Nagelkerke to value the wrong method. Simply use a regression tree/decision tree (e. g. CART algorithm) and you will get a clear cut-off.